# Why is CommandParameter always null?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, command, commandparameter

anybody an idea why CommandParameter is always null?

The class TransactionViewModel has the collection property of TransactionCommands to be displayed in the ItemsControl. The items are of type CommandViewModel.

TransactionBrowserViewModel has the command AddJobForSelectedTransactionCommand. The command to be passed as a parameter the CommandViewModel.

View Snipp:

```
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="4"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding TransactionCommands}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadButton Content="{Binding DisplayName}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                       Command="{Binding ViewModel.AddJobForSelectedTransactionCommand, ElementName=userControl}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

---

Codebehind of UserControl:

```
[Export]
public partial class TransactionBrowserView : UserControl, IView<TransactionBrowserViewModel>
{       
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public TransactionBrowserView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Import]
    public TransactionBrowserViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (TransactionBrowserViewModel)this.DataContext; }
        set { this.DataContext = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.DataContext = this;//or your viewmodel` is that you have added this line?

Comment: Are other bindings working? i.e DisplayName and CommandBinding?

Comment: Yes the other bindings work.
The DisplayName is visible and that the function CanExecute and execute can be performed.

Comment: You need to use English language for your post. Otherwise they will be closed?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've changed it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, sorry I have found the error.
It is located on the RadButton by Telerik. I have tested the scenario with a default button. Here it works without any problems.

Comment: I had a similar issue where a button style was consuming the event that passed a command parameter. Once I changed up the button, I noticed the parameter came through as the right object instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `ComandParameter` to the path of the `DataContext` of the `RadButton`, but I don't see that you have set anything to that `DataContext` anywhere.

Look into the Output window for information regarding your Binding errors... it should say something like 'There is no `DataContext` property on object XXX'.

What are you *trying* to bind to the `CommandParameter` property?

Comment: In the output window are no bindingerror to find, therefore also no binding errors should be present.

The command should be run directly, but first to be added to a CompositeCommand.

Comment: I've tried following binding CommandParameter = "{Binding}". It doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure that you have your WPF Trace Settings on even? Go to Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > WPF Trace Settings and at least set Data Binding to Warning or Error. Guessing binding paths also doesn't usually help... think... what object do you want to set as the `CommandParameter`? Does the binding have access to that object? Is it in the same scope as the `Command`?

Comment: I have checked the settings once again. It is set to warning.
As all other bindings in the ItemsControl will work, I'm assuming that there should be no access issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this binding

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="transactionList" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding TransactionCommands}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <telerik:RadButton Content="{Binding DisplayName}"
                         CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=transactionList}"
                         Command="{Binding ViewModel.AddJobForSelectedTransactionCommand, ElementName=userControl}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Give your ItemsControl (like `transactionList`) and set the binding of the `CommandParameter` to the `SelectedItem` of your transactionList.

or does this not do what you want.

```
<telerik:RadButton Content="{Binding DisplayName}"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                   Command="{Binding ViewModel.AddJobForSelectedTransactionCommand, ElementName=userControl}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.
That won't work for my scenario, because the button commands has a CanExecute method and bind the individual elements are not selected.

Comment: I tried CommandParameter = "{Binding}". It does not work, is also null.

Comment: I have the exact same code on two different views (same viewmodel same XAML). It works on one and gives me null on the other. Something is broken.